# Constructing a web-reading aid: row selector

Tags: javascript, css

I've been trying to make a row-marking script to help me read text online. When I read books I always use a ruler or paper. Online, I don't have this option and usually get lost in text.

```
W - move div up
S - move div down
```

[JS fiddle for my current effort (S = down, W = up)](http://jsfiddle.net/RxDpP/)

The best thing I could come up with is to have equal row height for all text-elements, but makes styling quite hard. Also, I would like to be able to run it in the console to enable it on any website (or install it as a add-on).

**Is there some better way to design a tool like this, that makes it more capable and adaptive to unknown content?**

- I can of course select text and I do that a lot. Usually, it results in me selecting only some words-> attention goes to that word, which is kind of what I want to avoid.
- I could also use a secondary window, which I do sometimes. But it's a bit wobbly and as soon as you click it disappears.
- A div that follows mouse-pointer is a possibility, but it's too shaky and feels like something got stuck on your finger.

EDIT: I updated the fiddle with the changes. I kept the javascript because without it you won't be able to move the ruler to the lower parts of the text.
[Updated reading-ruler](http://jsfiddle.net/RxDpP/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of JavaScript you could set a `position: fixed` for the .ruler. It will stay in the same place all the time so you can read the text with the .ruler element below it.

Here is the jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/RxDpP/1/

Comment: Very clever! It's also applicable to all sites if you add it through consol. Just have to do something about that styling...

Comment: Yes it has a wide variety of support and with a few extra styles you can style it the way you want to.